# Implement an SVG mask on a RECT with D3 (in Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to implement an SVG mask in D3, similar to this very simple [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bologna/o5j93f7e/), but I must have lost something in translation. My implementation all takes place in a class that renders a graph. I'm trying to apply the mask to define bounds for the graph, so that when the data exceeds those bounds, the graph is neatly clipped. When I apply the mask, the bars of the graph completely disappear. As far as I can tell the mask in the right place. HELP!

Here is where I define the mask in my `init()` function:

```
    // Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.
    this.graph = d3.select(this.config.id).append("svg:svg")
                        .attr("width", this.width + this.m[1] + this.m[3])
                        .attr("height", this.height + this.m[0] + this.m[2])                            
                    .append("svg:g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.m[3] + "," + this.m[0] + ")");

    var maskWidth  = 640;
    var maskHeight = 321;

    this.graph.append('svg:defs')      <------  I START DEFINING IT HERE !
        .call(function (defs) {
          // Appending the mask
          defs.append('svg:mask')
            .attr('id', 'mask')
            .attr('width', maskWidth)
            .attr('height', maskHeight)
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('y', 0)
            .call(function(mask) {
              mask.append('svg:rect')
                .attr('width', maskWidth)
                .attr('height', maskHeight)
                .attr('fill', '#ffffff')
            });
        });
```

Here is the Method that draws bars on the graph where I attempt to apply the mask (see the last line):

```
addBars: function (data){
                var numberOfBars = Math.floor(this.xMaximum);
                var barWidth = this.width/numberOfBars;

                // Generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
                var histogramData = d3.layout.histogram()
                    .bins(this.xScale.ticks(numberOfBars))
                    (data);    

                //console.trace('typeof: '+typeof this.xScale);
                var xScale = this.xScale;
                var yScale = this.yScale;
                var height = this.height;

                this.bars = this.graph.selectAll("bar")
                        .data(histogramData, function(d){ return d;})
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                        .attr("class","bar")
                        .attr("fill","steelblue")
                        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
                            var yOffset = height;
                            return "translate(" + (i * barWidth - barWidth/2) + ","+yOffset+")";
                            })
                        .attr("y", function(d,i) { 
                            var yPosition = yScale(d.length)- height;
                            return (yScale(d.length)-height); 
                            })
                        .attr("height", function(d) { 
                            return height - yScale(d.length);
                            })
                        .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
                        .attr('mask', 'url(#mask)');   <---- OVER HERE  !!!!
    },
```

Here is a link to the resulting HTML in Chrome Developer Tools (I've highlighted the `<defs>` and one of the graph bars that should be masked):[Chrome Developer Tools Dynamic HTML](http://www.jonahelgart.com/stackoverflow/HTMLoutput.jpg)

As far as I can tell everything looks good. This leads me to believe that the mask is mis-aligned with the bar, causing the bar to be invisible. However, in the developer tools, when I hover over the `<rect>` element, it shows it as overlaying the graph bars, so it doesn't seem like an alignment issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Lastly, I've made a jsfiddle of the class being used in my application (see the comments for the link.). Below is also the entire class for drawing the graph, just in case it would be helpful to see the code in context:

```
// HistogramGrapher class - constructor
var HistogramGrapher = function() {

    // assign default properties
    this.config = {
        id: "",
        xAxisLabel: "xAxis",
        yAxisLabel: "yAxis",
        width: 1000,
        height: 400,
        title: "Title",
        mean: 20
    };

    // define variables
    this.m = [40, 80, 40, 80]; // margins
    this.width; // width
    this.height; // height
    this.xAxisLabel;
    this.yAxisLabel;
    this.graph;
    this.bars; 
    this.lines;
    this.xScale;
    this.xScaleInvert;
    this.xAxis;
    this.yScale;
    this.yScaleInvert;
    this.yAxis;
    this.yMaximum = 25;
    this.xMaximum = 2 * this.config.mean;
}


// methods for this class
HistogramGrapher.prototype = {

    init: function (options) {
        // copy properties of `options` to `config`. Will overwrite existing ones.
        for(var prop in options) {
            if(options.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                this.config[prop] = options[prop];
            }
        }

        // update variables
        this.updateWidth(this.config.width);
        this.updateHeight(this.config.height);
        this.updateXMaximum(this.config.mean);

        // X scale will fit all values from datay[] within pixels 0-w
        this.xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, this.xMaximum])
                        .range([0, this.width]);

        this.xScaleInvert = d3.scale.linear()
                        .range([0, this.xMaximum])
                        .domain([0, this.width]);

        // Y scale 
        this.yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, this.yMaximum])
                        .range([this.height,0]);

        this.yScaleInvert = d3.scale.linear()
                        .range([0, this.yMaximum])
                        .domain([this.height,0]);


        // Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.
        this.graph = d3.select(this.config.id).append("svg:svg")
                            .attr("width", this.width + this.m[1] + this.m[3])
                            .attr("height", this.height + this.m[0] + this.m[2])                            
                        .append("svg:g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.m[3] + "," + this.m[0] + ")");

        var maskWidth  = 640;
        var maskHeight = 321;

        this.graph.append('svg:defs')
            .call(function (defs) {
              // Appending the mask
              defs.append('svg:mask')
                .attr('id', 'mask')
                .attr('width', maskWidth)
                .attr('height', maskHeight)
                .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('y', 0)
                .call(function(mask) {
                  mask.append('svg:rect')
                    .attr('width', maskWidth)
                    .attr('height', maskHeight)
                    .attr('fill', '#ffffff')
                });
            });



        // create xAxis
        this.xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.xScale)
            .tickSize(-this.height)
            .tickSubdivide(true);

        // create yAxis
        this.yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this.yScale)
            .tickSize(-this.width)
            .tickSubdivide(true)
            .orient("left");

        // Add the x-axis label.
        this.graph.append("text")
            .attr("class", "x label")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("x", this.width)
            .attr("y", this.height + 25)
            .text(this.config.xAxisLabel);

        // Add the y-axis label.
        this.graph.append("text")
            .attr("class", "y label")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("y", -30)
            .attr("dy", ".75em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .text(this.config.yAxisLabel);

        // add Title
        this.graph.append("text")
            .attr("x", this.width/2 )             
            .attr("y", -20  )               
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
            .style("font-size", "12px")                 
            .text(this.config.title);

        // Add the x-axis.
        this.graph.append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
              .call(this.xAxis);

        // Add the y-axis.
        this.graph.append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(this.yAxis);        
    },      

    updateWidth: function(width){
            this.width = width - this.m[1] - this.m[3];
    },

    updateHeight: function(height){
            this.height = height - this.m[0] - this.m[2]; // height 
    },  

    updateXMaximum: function(mean){
        this.xMaximum = 2.5 * mean;
    },

    addBars: function (data){
                var numberOfBars = Math.floor(this.xMaximum);
                var barWidth = this.width/numberOfBars;

                // Generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
                var histogramData = d3.layout.histogram()
                    .bins(this.xScale.ticks(numberOfBars))
                    (data);    

                //console.trace('typeof: '+typeof this.xScale);
                var xScale = this.xScale;
                var yScale = this.yScale;
                var height = this.height;

                this.bars = this.graph.selectAll("bar")
                        .data(histogramData, function(d){ return d;})
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                        .attr("class","bar")
                        .attr("fill","steelblue")
                        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
                            var yOffset = height;
                            return "translate(" + (i * barWidth - barWidth/2) + ","+yOffset+")";
                            })
                        .attr("y", function(d,i) { 
                            var yPosition = yScale(d.length)- height;
                            return (yScale(d.length)-height); 
                            })
                        .attr("height", function(d) { 
                            return height - yScale(d.length);
                            })
                        .attr("width", barWidth - 1)
                        .attr('mask', 'url(#mask)');
    },

    addLine: function (data){  // the data must be in the form " [ {'x':x1, 'y':y1} , {'x':x2, 'y':y2} , {'x':x3, 'y':y3} ... ]
        var xScale = this.xScale;
        var yScale = this.yScale;
        var height = this.height;

        // create a line function that can convert data[] into x and y points
        var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
            // assign the X function to plot our line as we wish
            .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
            .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
            .interpolate("linear");

        this.lines = this.graph.append("path")
                        .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
                        .attr("class", "line")
                        .attr("stroke", "green")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                        .attr("fill","none");

    },

    clear: function () {
        var bars = d3.selectAll(".bar").remove();
        var lines = d3.selectAll(".line").remove();
    },

    getxScale: function () {
        return this.xScale;
    },

    getxScaleInvert: function () {
        return this.xScaleInvert;
    }
}
```

Comment: a jsfiddle would be helpful in this case, since the code is not that slim :)

Comment: @tomtomtom You'd like to see the graphing class being used in jsfiddle? to see that the graph disappears with the mask?

Comment: yes  being able to see what is actually going on would surely be helpful

Comment: @tomtomtom I really appreciate you wanting to dive into the full code - I added it to a [new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bologna/p94tagg1/). See line 191 for where the mask is applied. There's a lot to digest, so if you have questions, ask, and I will clarify or modify the code to simplify it. Thanks!

Comment: @tomtomtom I should clarify... In the jsfiddle the mask is currently commented out and the bars will appear. If you uncomment the mask to apply it, the bars will disappear. After running the simulation many times, the bars will eventually be taller than the graph area. That is when I want them clipped.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I saw what's going on. You should apply the clipping mask to the bars and the line by appending a clipping mask to the graph area:

```
//clipping mask
yourSvg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "chart-area")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", yourXcoordinates)
    .attr("y", yourYcoordinates)
    .attr("width", 333) //this was the width provided by the webinspector 
    .attr("height", 649) //this was the height provided by the webinspector;
```

then when you plot the line and the bars, add this to both of the generators

```
.attr("clip-path", "url(#chart-area)")
```

and this should give you the clipping you're looking for. Basically what it does is clip everything outside the area of that rectangle, so if you plot it correctly, it should clip out unwanted things

Comment: It's half working! It works on the line, but not the bars. Could you take a look at the bars (line 199) in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bologna/njp2ubd3/)? 

For bars, first I create the bar:  `this.bars = this.graph.selectAll("bar").data(foo) .enter()` 

then append the bar and add the mask `.append("rect").attr("clip-path", "url(#mask)")` But something is not right.

Comment: that's strange, I see that you could either hide the line or the bars, but not both. Since I'm kind of lost in your code, I'd suggest you to do the following:

Set up a 'g' element, give it the clip path, and plot the elements inside it, both the line and the rectangles, this way it should work! I believe that's because of this, even with graphic programs you can't mask multiple items with the same mask, unless they are grouped, and since we're working with svg the principle should apply as well